# php displaying multiple level of array

Tags: php, arrays

Please I have an array tree like this

```
[
    {
     "item01": "item01 value",
      "images": [
            {
                "url": "sampleurl",
                "imageDesc": "sampleImgDesc"
            }
        ],
      "item02": "item02 value",
    }
]
```

Please how can I display "images -> url" and "images -> imageDesc"

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `echo $array[0]['images'][0]['url']`

Answer (score 0):

You can display like this

```php
echo sprintf(
    "url : %s, imageDesc : %s", 
    $array[0]['images'][0]['url'], 
    $array[0]['images'][0]['imageDesc']
);
```